# Show folder file public in shared windows hosting

Tags: permissions, plesk, shared-hosting, windows-hosting

Hello we have shared windows hosting on hostgator. i have created sub domain and i want to show all files public like given image.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxPsj.jpg)

Basically i want to make one directory public which directory and all files from that directory anyone can access. in shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't published your files properly. You can follow this steps:

1. Please open your project with Visual Studio tool
2. On the Solution Explorer windows (which is normally located on the top right hand corner of the VS tool), right click your project and select Publish
3. Please kindly publish it to a local folder, such as C:\Project
4. Please just upload whatever files/folders you see on C:\Project to the server via FTP and your site will work fine

You can also publish using Webdeploy option. You said that you are using Plesk control panel, you can read this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/